# How to include component link in the parent component for translation?

Tags: 2011, translation-manager

I noticed that when sending Component for translation, Tridion is NOT including the nested Component Link for translation. As a result, I have to send the nested Component Link  manually. The support team is telling me that it is not possible to include the nested Component in Tridion 2011. How do you handle this problem?

Comment: Component Links are not translatable. Linked Components are not automatically sent for translation. I think you might be able to create a plugin for Translation Manager that resolves the linked components that you are interested in. But be careful: with less manual control often come higher translation bills.

Comment: I do mean "linked components" in my question. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: We added the following feature to SDL Web 8, which will be in the next on-premise version: "In Schemas, you can configure Component fields that are linked to other Components to also be translated when the 'container' Component is sent for translation..." See the [cloud docs (accessed 2016-11-28) for more information](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Cloud-v1/GUID-7FFD86C9-C0CF-46DA-AEC9-70E20BEB16EE). Also, in Web 8, the TM plugin approach has since been deprecated in favor of using the Event System instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a plug in sample about how to create a TM Plug In that adds component links for Translation

[Developing a Translation Manager Plug In](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2014/01/developing-translation-manager-plug-ins.html)